# React Component Returning Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined has no properties

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am building a nav bar with a logout button. Ideally, I would like the user to be redirected back to homepage when the log out button is being clicked. However, I am getting an error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined has no properties when the logout button is being clicked.

Can someone kindly advice?

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../favicon.png';
import AuthService from '../Services/AuthServices';
import { AuthContext } from '../AuthContext';

const Navbar = props => {
    const { isAuthenticated, user, setIsAuthenticated, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const onClickLogoutHandler = () => {
        AuthService.logout().then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                setUser(data.user);
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
                this.props.history.push('/')            }
        });
    }

    const unauthenticatedNavBar = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark px-sm-5">
                    <Link to='/'>
                        <img src={logo} alt="store"
                            className='navbar-brand' />
                    </Link>
                    <ul className='navbar-nav align-item-center'>
                        <li className="nav-item ml=5">
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                                PRODUCTS
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div className="input-group">
                        <div className="input-group-prepend">
                            <div className="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">@</div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Input group example" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon" />
                    </div>


                    <ul className='navbar-nav align-item-center'>
                        <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                            <Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">
                                Sign Up
                            </Link>
                        </li>

                        <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                            <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">
                                Log In
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <Link to='/sell' className="ml-5">
                        <button type='button' className="btn btn-danger">SELL</button>
                    </Link>

                </nav>
            </>
        )
    }

    const authenticatedNavBar = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark px-sm-5">
                    <Link to='/'>
                        <img src={logo} alt="store"
                            className='navbar-brand' />
                    </Link>
                    <ul className='navbar-nav align-item-center'>
                        <li className="nav-item ml=5">
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                                PRODUCTS
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div className="input-group">
                        <div className="input-group-prepend">
                            <div className="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">@</div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Input group example" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon" />
                    </div>


                    <ul className='navbar-nav align-item-center'>
                        <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                            <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">
                                {user.username}
                            </Link>
                        </li>

                        <Link to='/sell' className="ml-5">
                            <button type='button' className="btn btn-danger">SELL</button>
                        </Link>

                        <button type="button"
                            className="btn btn-link nav-item nav-link"
                            onClick={onClickLogoutHandler}>Logout</button>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </>
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            {!isAuthenticated ? unauthenticatedNavBar() : authenticatedNavBar()}
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError)` usually occurs when a Promise is rejected and your code doesn't catch it. Is it from your `AuthService.logout()` call?

Comment: hello, yes it is from my AuthSerivce.logout

```

logout : ()=>{
        return fetch(`${BACKEND_URL_USERS}/logout`, { credentials: 'include' })
                .then(res => {
                    res.json())
                .then(data => data);
    }

```